# How do I include section information in indexPathForSelectedRow

Tags: xcode, uitableview, segue, sections

I have a table with sections, populated by an array which is comprised of four arrays. How do I modify the indexPathForSelectedRow statements in the prepare for segue method to include section information?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"plantSaveSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *grassType = [segue destinationViewController];

        //grassType.selectedPlant = [grassArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
        grassType.selectedPlant = [plantArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for one section, but what do I do for four sections?

Comment: Not sure I really understand your question, but NSIndexPath already does have section information, simply look at selectedRowIndex.section.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the clue to simply fix the problem. In my selectedRowIndex path I had omitted to completely define the path. You comment fired the appropriate neurons and I fixed my problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 NSIntegers in the .h file

```
NSInteger selectedSection;
NSInteger selectedRow;
```

and now in your viewDidLoad(), initialize these to "-1"

```
selectedSection = -1;
selectedRow = -1;
```

Now in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


selectedSection = indexPath.section;
selectedRow = indexPath.row;

//Now performSegue here
}
```

After that

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"plantSaveSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *grassType = [segue destinationViewController];

        if(selectedSection == 0){
             grassType.selectedPlant = [firstArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];}
        else if(selectedSection == 1){
             grassType.selectedPlant = [secondArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];}
        else if(selectedSection == 2){
             grassType.selectedPlant = [thirdArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];}
        else if(selectedSection == 3{
             grassType.selectedPlant = [fourthArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];}

    }
}
```

**Hope This Helps**

Comment: Thank you for the help. The segue fires and the next view is presented, but no data is passed. I am also getting a warning on the line NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];, which is logical because it is now an unused variable.

Comment: is it not showing the data if you tap on any row in the tableView? are you using just one type of DetailViewController? and I would want to see how "DetailViewController" gets populated to further assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help and guidance. The answer was distressingly simple, type in the complete and correct path for the appropriate item in the table. See below:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"plantSaveSegue"])
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *grassType = [segue destinationViewController];
    grassType.selectedPlant = [[plantArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.section]objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
}
}
```